# Adding a TypeConverter to dynamic properties

Tags: c#, propertygrid, typeconverter, dynamic-properties

I am coding a C# forms application where an object has custom properties for a `PropertyGrid`. These custom properties are displayed at runtime.

Here is my code:

```
private readonly List<CustomProperty> props = new List<CustomProperty>();
[Browsable(false)]
public List<CustomProperty> properties { get { return props; } }

private Dictionary<string, object> values = new Dictionary<string, object>();

public object this[string name]
{
    get { object val; values.TryGetValue(name, out val); return val; }
    set 
    { 
        values[name] = value;
    }
}
private class CustomWebpageObjectTypeUserObjectConverter : ExpandableObjectConverter
{
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(ITypeDescriptorContext context, object value, Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        var stdProps = base.GetProperties(context, value, attributes);
        CustomWebpageObjectTypeUserObject obj = value as CustomWebpageObjectTypeUserObject;
        List<CustomProperty> customProps = obj == null ? null : obj.properties;
        PropertyDescriptor[] props = new PropertyDescriptor[stdProps.Count + (customProps == null ? 0 : customProps.Count)];
        stdProps.CopyTo(props, 0);
        if (customProps != null)
        {
            int index = stdProps.Count;
            foreach (CustomProperty prop in customProps)
            {
                CustomWebpageObjectTypeUserObjectCustomPropertyDescriptor customWebpageObjectTypeUserObjectCustomPropertyDescriptor = new CustomWebpageObjectTypeUserObjectCustomPropertyDescriptor(prop);
                props[index++] = customWebpageObjectTypeUserObjectCustomPropertyDescriptor;
            }
        }
        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(props);
    }
}

public class CustomWebpageObjectTypeUserObjectCustomPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
{
    private readonly CustomProperty prop;
    public CustomWebpageObjectTypeUserObjectCustomPropertyDescriptor(CustomProperty prop)
        : base(prop.name, null)
    {
        this.prop = prop;
    }
    public override string Category { get { return prop.category; } }
    public override string Description { get { return prop.description; } }
    public override string Name { get { return prop.name; } }
    public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component) { return ((CustomWebpageObjectTypeUserObject)component)[prop.name] != null; }
    public override void ResetValue(object component) { ((CustomWebpageObjectTypeUserObject)component)[prop.name] = null; }
    public override bool IsReadOnly { get { return false; } }
    public override Type PropertyType { get { return prop.type; } }
    public override bool CanResetValue(object component) { return true; }
    public override Type ComponentType { get { return typeof(CustomWebpageObjectTypeUserObject); } }
    public override void SetValue(object component, object value) 
    { 
        ((CustomWebpageObjectTypeUserObject)component)[prop.name] = value;
        prop._value = value;
    }
    public override object GetValue(object component) 
    { 
        return ((CustomWebpageObjectTypeUserObject)component)[prop.name] ?? prop._value; 
    }
}
```

This code works correctly with simple set and get values. What I am needing some advice with is how to display a drop down list with dynamic properties that are created at runtime.

I understand how to use a `TypeConverter` to get a `StandardValuesCollection`, yet am not sure how to do this with dynamic properties. Do I need to add this attribute to a dynamic property, and does this need to be done in the `CustomWebpageObjectTypeUserObjectCustomPropertyDescriptor` class? Is there an override that I need to implement to add this attribute? Do I need to do this another way?

Thanks in advance.